# convert Binary code into TEXT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to convert binary code in to text/string in MATLAB? I have converted the binary code in decimal value, but couldn't find any way to convert that decimal value into a character using MATLAB according to the ASCII table. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [char](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) ?

```
>> char(65:90)
ans = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

and

```
>> char(bin2dec('1010101'))
ans = 'U'
```

Comment: Thank you, and yes I was looking for this

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a few approaches you can use to achieve your goal:

1) Using the [native2unicode](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/native2unicode.html) function (this supports different encodings, which can be explicitly defined in the second input argument):

```
native2unicode([77 65 84 76 65 66]) % Output: char 'MATLAB'
```

2) Using the [char](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) function (it supports both Unicode and ASCII encodings, but the conversion is automatically performed):

```
char([77 65 84 76 65 66]) % Output: char 'MATLAB'
```

3) Using the underlying Java framework:

```
java.lang.String(uint8([77 65 84 76 65 66])) % java.lang.String "MATLAB"
```

Comment: Thank you. it's helpful @Tommaso